# Getting OpenSSL ca.config file to work with PHP?

Tags: php, ssl, openssl

I did a bunch of searching, but I couldn't find an answer. I'm posting this here because it seems more like an OpenSSL issue rather than a PHP one, although I can use this CA configuration to create certs from the command line, so there is something that PHP doesn't like about it.

When calling `openssl_pkey_new()` in PHP, I'm getting the error:

`Error loading request_extensions_section section v3_req of /path/to/ca.config`.

I'm passing the path of the ca.config file to `openssl_pkey_new()` via the config array, and PHP is opening the file.

The ca.config file looks like:

```
[ ca ]
default_ca = MyClientCA

[ crl_ext ]
issuerAltName=issuer:copy
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always

[ MyClientCA ]
dir = /site/path/ssl/ca
new_certs_dir = $dir
unique_subject = no
certificate = $dir/MyClientCA.public
database = $dir/certindex
private_key = $dir/MyClientCA.key
serial = $dir/MyClientCA.srl
default_days = 3650
default_md = sha1
policy = myca_policy
x509_extensions = myca_extensions
crlnumber = $dir/crlnumber
default_crl_days = 730

[ myca_policy ]
commonName = supplied
stateOrProvinceName = supplied
countryName = optional
emailAddress = optional
organizationName = supplied
organizationalUnitName = optional

[ myca_extensions ]
basicConstraints = critical,CA:TRUE
keyUsage = critical,any
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid:always,issuer
keyUsage = digitalSignature,keyEncipherment,cRLSign,keyCertSign
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
crlDistributionPoints = @crl_section
subjectAltName  = @alt_names
authorityInfoAccess = @ocsp_section

[ v3_ca ]
basicConstraints = critical,CA:TRUE,pathlen:0
keyUsage = critical,any
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid:always,issuer
keyUsage = digitalSignature,keyEncipherment,cRLSign,keyCertSign
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
crlDistributionPoints = @crl_section
subjectAltName  = @alt_names
authorityInfoAccess = @ocsp_section

[alt_names]
DNS.0 = Sparkling Intermidiate CA 1
DNS.1 = Sparkling CA Intermidiate 1

[crl_section]
URI.0 = http://pki.sparklingca.com/SparklingRoot.crl
URI.1 = http://pki.backup.com/SparklingRoot.crl

[ocsp_section]
caIssuers;URI.0 = http://pki.sparklingca.com/SparklingRoot.crt
caIssuers;URI.1 = http://pki.backup.com/SparklingRoot.crt
OCSP;URI.0 = http://pki.sparklingca.com/ocsp/
OCSP;URI.1 = http://pki.backup.com/ocsp/
```

Unfortunately, the error `error loading request_extensions_section section v3_req` isn't very useful.

I don't have a `request_extensions` section in the file. There's an `x509_extensions` directive that points to `myca_extensions` but that doesn't seem to have anything wrong with it.

There isn't a `v3_req` section either. There's a `v3_ca` section, but again, I'm not seeing anything wrong with it.

How can I get more details about what's wrong with the configuration file?

**Update**

I've tried a bunch of things.

I tried copying the file from the system's default openssl.conf, but that just changes the error to:

```
error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value
```

There's quite a lot of people online asking about that error, but none have any useful replies.

I switched to a basic config:

```
[ ca ]
default_ca = ClientCA

[ ClientCA ]
dir = /path/var/ssl
new_certs_dir = $dir/pk12
unique_subject = no
certificate = $dir/ca/ClientCA.public
database = $dir/ca/certindex
private_key = $dir/ca/ClientCA.key
serial = $dir/ca/ClientCA.srl
default_days = 3650
default_md = sha256
policy = myca_policy
x509_extensions = myca_extensions

[ myca_policy ]
commonName = supplied
stateOrProvinceName = supplied
countryName = optional
emailAddress = optional
organizationName = supplied
organizationalUnitName = optional

[ myca_extensions ]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = critical,any
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid:always,issuer
keyUsage = digitalSignature,keyEncipherment,cRLSign,keyCertSign
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
crlDistributionPoints = @crl_section
subjectAltName  = @alt_names
authorityInfoAccess = @ocsp_section
```

But same error:

```
error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value
```

The config works just fine creating certs from the command line.